# NodeJS child_process.spawn() behaving different when run as systemd service on Debian 10

Tags: debian, systemd, node.js, sip

I am working on a NodeJS application, that runs expressJS and uses twinkle to dial a telephonenumber.

Given the following function:

```
export const call = (telNr: string, res: Response|undefined = undefined) => {
    const endOfLine = require("os").EOL;
    const process = spawn("/usr/bin/twinkle", ["-c"], {shell: true});
    let registered = false;
    process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        if (/registration succeeded/.test(data.toString())) {
            if (!registered) {
                registered = true;
                process.stdin.write("call " + telNr + endOfLine);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    try {
                        process.stdin.write("bye" + endOfLine);
                        process.stdin.write("exit" + endOfLine);
                    } catch {
                        // War schon zu
                    }
                }, 10000);
            } // Else -> Scheint das zweite mal ausgegeben zu werden.
        }

        if (/486 Busy here/.test(data.toString())) {
            // Belegt
            process.stdin.write("exit" + endOfLine);
        }
    });

    process.on("exit", (exit) => {
        if (res !== undefined) {
            res.json({code: exit});
        }
    });
};
```

The function is for debugging purposes called via an url (that's why there's the optional `res`-parameter.

***now to the problem***

When I start the app as root with `node index.js`, and open the given URL the wanted SIP-Phone rings for 10 seconds.

When the app is started as service via systemd, the childprocess is immediately closed with exitcode 134.

systemd-unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Besuchermanagement Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /srv/node/besuchermanagement/dist/index.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I hope this isn't offtopic, since I am not sure if this problem is related to my code, or a misconfiguration of my service in systemd.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you pick `type=forking`?

Comment: @muru after reading the docs for systemd I tried forking, but this didn't help, same problem as with "Simple"

Comment: "When I start the app as root with `node index.js`" - does this command depend on anything in that directory and needs it to be the [`WorkingDirectory`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=)?

Comment: @muru I just verified that this is unfortunatelly not the case. Setting the WorkingDirectory in the service did not fix the problem. When calling node /srv/node/besuchermanagement/dist/index.js from PWD / the error does not occur.